# Divide and Conquer Matrix Multiplication // Error with recursive base case?

Tags: java, matrix-multiplication, divide-and-conquer

I'm trying to implement a divide and conquer matrix multiplication for matrices of even size but somehow my results are really messed up. My initial idea was to split an n x n matrix into four n/2 x n/2 matrices. However, when i run my code with following operation, a weird result occurs which i can't seem to find a relation to that would lead me to the mistake.

Input:

```
1 2 1 2    *   1 0 0 0   = 14 20 14 20
3 4 3 4        0 1 0 0     30 44 30 44
5 6 5 6        0 0 1 0     134 156 134 156
7 8 7 8        0 0 0 1     182 212 182 212
```

This is the the code i came up with:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {


        int[][] fst = {{ 1, 2, 1, 2 }, { 3, 4, 3, 4}, { 5, 6, 5, 6 }, { 7, 8, 7, 8 }};
        int[][] snd = {{ 1, 0, 0, 0 }, { 0, 1, 0, 0 }, { 0, 0, 1, 0 }, { 0, 0, 0, 1 }};

        print_mat(matrix_mult_dc(fst,snd));
    }

    static int[][] matrix_mult_dc(int[][] fst, int[][] snd) {
        int n = fst.length;
        int[][] res = new int[n][n];
        if (n == 1) {
            res[0][0] = fst[0][0]*snd[0][0];
            return res;
        } else {

            // dividing a
            int[][] fst_a = new int[n / 2][n / 2];
            int[][] fst_b = new int[n / 2][n / 2];
            int[][] fst_c = new int[n / 2][n / 2];
            int[][] fst_d = new int[n / 2][n / 2];

            for (int i = 0; i < n / 2; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < n / 2; j++) {
                    fst_a[i][j] = fst[i][j];
                }
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < n / 2; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < n / 2; j++) {
                    fst_b[i][j] = fst[i][j + (n / 2)];
                }
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < n / 2; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < n / 2; j++) {
                    fst_c[i][j] = fst[i + (n / 2)][j];
                }
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < n / 2; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < n / 2; j++) {
                    fst_d[i][j] = fst[i + (n / 2)][j + (n / 2)];
                }
            }

            //dividing b
            int[][] snd_e = new int[n / 2][n / 2];
            int[][] snd_f = new int[n / 2][n / 2];
            int[][] snd_g = new int[n / 2][n / 2];
            int[][] snd_h = new int[n / 2][n / 2];

            for (int i = 0; i < n / 2; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < n / 2; j++) {
                    snd_e[i][j] = fst[i][j];
                }
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < n / 2; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < n / 2; j++) {
                    snd_f[i][j] = fst[i][j + (n / 2)];
                }
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < n / 2; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < n / 2; j++) {
                    snd_g[i][j] = fst[i + (n / 2)][j];
                }
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < n / 2; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < n / 2; j++) {
                    snd_h[i][j] = fst[i + (n / 2)][j + (n / 2)];
                }
            }

            //recursion

            int[][] r = matrix_add(matrix_mult_dc(fst_a,snd_e), matrix_mult_dc(fst_b,snd_g));
            int[][] s = matrix_add(matrix_mult_dc(fst_a,snd_f), matrix_mult_dc(fst_b,snd_h));
            int[][] t = matrix_add(matrix_mult_dc(fst_c,snd_e), matrix_mult_dc(fst_d,snd_g));
            int[][] u = matrix_add(matrix_mult_dc(fst_c,snd_f), matrix_mult_dc(fst_d,snd_h));

            //merging res

            for (int i = 0; i < n/2; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < n/2; j++) {
                    res[i][j] = r[i][j];
                }
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < n/2; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < n/2; j++) {
                    res[i][j+n/2] = s[i][j];
                }
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < n/2; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < n/2; j++) {
                    res[i+n/2][j] = t[i][j];
                }
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < n/2; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < n/2; j++) {
                    res[i+n/2][j+n/2] = u[i][j];
                }
            }

        }
        return res;
    }

    static int[][] matrix_add(int[][] fst, int[][] snd) {
        int[][] res = new int[fst.length][fst.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < fst.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < fst.length; j++) {
                res[i][j] = fst[i][j] + snd[i][j];
            }
        }
        return res;
    }

    static void print_mat(int[][] matrix) {
        for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++) {
                System.out.print(matrix[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is your exact problem?? Why your result matrix is not true in your example?

Comment: yes, i can't figure out why

Comment: You cannot split n*n matrix to four matrix  n/2 * n/2!  You can split it to n/2 *2/n